# How to to implement Web- socket in SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, websocket, soap-client

I have a winform client app and Soap WebService.
Now, I only connect one way from client to Service.
How could I connect from Service to Client when have something event?
Could I implement Web-socket with SOAP Service?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if your runtime is .NET 4.5 (which is when Web Sockets were implemented).

Comment: Could I implement WebSocket into exists WebService project?